# SSD Wear_Leveling_Count = 17

Tags: ssd, smartctl

I have just checked my SSD drive (Samsung SSD 750 EVO 120GB) with smartctl.
The result is:

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       2141
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       839
177 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0013   096   096   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       17
179 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot   0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0013   100   099   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0032   067   051   000    Old_age   Always       -       33
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       4
235 Unknown_Attribute       0x0012   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       513
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       4263372302
```

What does the Wear_Leveling_Count 17 mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value you refer to is in the 'RAW' column, and isn't easy to interpret - it depends heavily on the vendor and firmware. But that's ok, it's not intended for you to interpret.

You basically only need to worry about the 'VALUE' column, as this is the normalised value that is actually useful. In your case, it's 96 (out of a maximum of 100 in this case, but not all SMART counters have a max of 100)

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/20439/14490) has a good summary of how to interpret SMART output